# Are objects created from enums created using the New keyword stored on Stack or the Heap

Tags: vb.net, enums

I want to ask about `Enums`.

`Enums` from ValueType are stored in `Stack`

But when I use it like this:

```
 Enum A
        A
        B
        C
    End Enum
    Dim _A As New A
```

Are `Dim _A As New A` stored in the heap or on stack?

Comment: You said yourself that it's a value type and value types are stored on the stack.

Comment: But I think objects store in heap

Comment: An object has a type and that may be a value type or a reference type.  If it's a value type then that object is stored on the stack and if it's a reference type then it's stored on the heap.

Comment: Thank you so much
if i create object and object just have variable integer will stored in stack?

Comment: You can answer that question for yourself with the information you already have.  I will not be contributing here further.

Comment: Value types are not always stored on the stack.  For example, if a class has a property that is a value type, it will be stored on the heap with the object instance.

Comment: Thank you Then **Dim _A As New A** will be stored on the stack right? just classes stored on the heap?